# Can I use a SSR to switch on/off an electronic ballast?

Tags: solid-state-relay, electronic-ballast

It's not appropiate to use a SSR to switch on/off magnetic ballast (used with HID lamps), because it's an inductive load and the Triac inside the SSR cut off while there is still current flowing. That produce flickering.

Can I use an SSR to switch on/off an electronic ballast without adverse side effects?

Comment: I would look at zero-cross current sending SSRs for an inductive application like this.

Comment: *"Triac inside the SSR cut off while there is still current flowing."* No, not possible. The triac conducts until the current drops to zero. The flickering is caused by the delay until the triac is triggered again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve that is use SCRs. They have 1/2 cycle to commutate. We did that with 500V 100 horsepower DC motors, no problems. There were 8 of them on extruders. I do not know if you can purchase them any more. You can also add to the snubber circuit.

Comment: It sound good (and Aliexpress carry SCR) and I will try it.

Comment: Good luck and let us know how you do. Glad I could help!

Comment: Using a SSR to switch a ‘iron’ ballast might be problematic, but switching an electronic ballast should not be a problem. An electronic ballast is effectively a switch mode power supply so should be no different from , say, your PC. I would suggest you consult the ballast manufacturer to confirm.

Comment: It have been working flawlessly for several month.